# dismissViewController but keep reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Lets say I have an app which basically exist of a tabbarcontroller with views. One of the views has a button which presents a modal viewcontroller. The purpose of this viewcontroller is to enter some data like a name and when pressing on start it starts recording so it also keeps a reference to the time and displays the total amount of recording time.

(After clicking the start button the button changes to a stop button)

During recording the user can click the close button which will dismiss the viewcontroller (holding the variables like name and recording time) and the app returns to its tabbarcontroller with views. When the user presses the button (which presents the modal viewcontroller) again while recording it must show the viewcontroller with the data entered previously (name, total amount of recording time).

So this data must be kept alive after the following code runs:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
     [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The code above will dismiss the viewcontroller but also destroys the variables in that viewcontroller. What would be the best way to keep the variables entered in that viewcontroller after dismissing it?

Should the tabbarcontroller's view be responsible for this data? Or should I keep a reference to my modal viewcontroller and keep it alive in the background? And how would I do this in code?

Finally when the user does stop the recording by clicking on the stop button in the modal view controller and presses the close button this view should be destroyed to preserve memory of course.

Comment: Declare your ViewController's object in .h file simple

Comment: So basically you are saying, create an instance of that modal viewcontroller and set that viewcontroller to nil when closing it (while not recording of course)

Comment: See my answer below i tested it on sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store whole instance of `ViewController` you should create an Singleton class with deallocation aborting method:

```
-(void)dealloc {
   abort();
}
```

But i think you want to store only a few information from it. You could pass it using `viewWillDissapear` method ant there called `topViewController` (in `UINavigationController` based app) and assign some variables to destination.

Also you could use singleton data model and assign values to this when you dismiss controller.

What i suggest you to do is strongly separate dataModel from ViewController to separate class.

Comment: Right I get what you're going at. Something like:
Have a model of the recorded object. Set the data in this model during recording. Then just simply dismiss and destroy the viewcontroller and when its going to appear again just get the data from the model.

Comment: if you are going to use a singleton please don't put abort() in the dealloc method, dispatch_once is the standard for creating pseudo-singletons

Answer (score 1):

Steps for achieving this:

Declare your Modal ViewController's object in your ViewController's .h file.

Initialize it in viewDidload.

Present it where ever you want.

Whenever you dismiss your modal viewcontroller its variables remain save.

Until you reinitialize your object or pop the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

2 words - Delegate pattern

It's good to separate things. If the controller is supposed to create some data, then define a protocol with one method, e.g.

```
-(void)controller:(MYController *)controller didEnterData:(MYDataWrapper *)data;
```

When the user taps `close`, send the message to the delegate. When you are creating the controller, set up the delegate. Simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can store your required data using NSUserDefaults before the view gets dismissed and, fetch the data using NSUserDefaults when the view loads.

Comment: Not really practical because it also contains a timer which starts when the start button is pressed. I think I'm creating a singleton data model which holds my data.